# Which $_SERVER variable should be used?

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to create a link in a PHP script that will take me to the main part of my address (In bold):   **http://localhost:8888**/index.php

I could put the exact link in myself but thought if I use the $_SERVER variable then it would allow for a degree for flexibility if I move the file etc.

I did a `vardump($_SERVER)` and it appears that `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` contains the data that I require, however it also seems that this may not be an ideal variable to use:
[How secure is HTTP_ORIGIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566378/how-secure-http-origin-is)

Is this the correct way to create a dynamic link or is there an alternative?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, it seems like [How secure HTTP_ORIGIN is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566378/how-secure-http-origin-is) is more about how secure `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` is concerning requests form 3rd party websites. You will probably be safe if you only want to create link. You should however use `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_PORT` as @ThiagoElias answered.

Comment: Why can you not just use a relative URI? `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be extra flexible you could check if https or http is used and if a port other then default 80 or 443 (https) is used, also meaning if no port is defined in the URL.

```
function url(){
    $port = null;
    if( ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '80') && ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') ) {
        $port = ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    }

    $protocol = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http://' : 'https://';

    return $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $port;
}
```

Comment: HTTPS use port 443 by default, not 80, so your function will add a port in the URL even if there wasn't in the original one if the user is on a HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 4):

try to use

```
$address = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
```