# Get only a specified url

Tags: php, regex

I want to check only sites finished in : `*.test.com` and `*.test1.com`
I tried :

```
if((preg_match('.\w+.test.com', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) or (preg_match('.\w+.test1.com', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))){
}
```

Comment: Try $urlcheck = expload("test.com",$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);  if(isset($urlcheck[1])) // it means it has test.com so your code goes here. Try it for both  test.com and *.test1.com

Comment: PHP requires delimiters for its regular expressions, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php. Those regexs should have been throwing errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, you want the most reliable way to break down any given url. For this, you can use PHP's [built-in `parse_url` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Then, you want to check whether or not it ends in `test.com` or `test1.com`, which you can do using a regex:

```
if (preg_match('/test1?\.com$/', $host)) {
    //match
}
```

The regex works like this:

- `test`: matches a string literal *"test"*
- `1?`: Matches a literal `1`, but it's optional, so both `test` and `test1` will match
- `\.`: a literal dot match
- `com`: literal match for com
- `$`: end of string. The expression will only match if the string ***ends*** in `test.com` or `test1.com`.

---

Just a word of warning: `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']`, and in fact almost none of the `$_SERVER` values are to be trusted. You can read more on the subject here ( + linked pages)

[How secure is HTTP_ORIGIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566378/how-secure-is-http-origin)

Answer (score 0):

You could use str_pos. Str_pos will search inside the string,link,url.. 
The documentation [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Here is a little example

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], 'test.com') !== false) {
    echo "found it";
}
```

Comment: You're not checking for `test1.com`. you've tried to edit my answer: please read the question again: OP wants to check for _"test.com"_ ***and*** _"test1.com"_. In addition to `test1` not being checked. If I owned a domain like _"com.org"_, and had a _"test"_ subdomain, your check would not pick up on `HTTP_ORIGIN` being `test.com.org`