# $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] doesn't work

Tags: php

When I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']`.

```html
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] ;
```

Return
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN in D:\xampp\htdocs\safe\test.php on line 12

What is Wrong?!

Comment: `What is Wrong?!` Using HTML snippets to display PHP code is wrong.

Comment: It just mean that the `Origin` header has not been provided when the page was requested.

Comment: what are you using it for? perhaps we can suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: It's because your browser not send origin request. so the php not send response the origin.

Comment: use `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){ echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']; }`

Answer (score 12):

The `Origin` header isn't sent by all browsers.

Depending what you're trying to do, another option is to use the `Referer` header:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

By the way, note that request headers are ultimately controlled by the user, so can't be fully trusted.

Comment: as long as you dont trust HTTP_REFERER as it is set by the browser. can be faked, or often emptied by various software for security

Comment: More Info Here about it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566378/how-secure-is-http-origin

Comment: @Dagon I demand an upvote! `:P` *just kidding, as this is as bad as asking money to strangers*

Comment: @Dagon Why extra software dude? Why not Firebug, Developer Tools? They are capable of emulating, simulating, confusing, collapsing and finally, crashing the server.

Comment: I meant some software a user may run may automatically empty it. i have seen various "internet security" software people run on their PC do this.

Comment: @Dagon Even I am doing it. OWASP? TamperHTTP? There are 1000s. But what I meant was, even the Chrome F12 Dev tools are capable of doing it.

Comment: i think we agree.

Comment: I use a SoapClient to another server and I want know Who's request

Comment: @smko SOAP Client huh? You need to provide more information dude.

Comment: I want to each site, which will be submitted information related to the site . But I know exactly the same site that will be submitted, and it is not Api someone else ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Please review this answer, or even delete it, as it's misleading.

Comment: @PedroLobito Sure, thanks for getting this to me... `:)`

Comment: @PedroLobito I guess either if you can update the answer as per the latest standard, or I'll just delete it... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar There never was a secure way of using `HTTP_REFERER` as it can be easily spoofed. I'd delete the answer.

Comment: How is either header "insecure"? Sure, they can be spoofed by a client, but they can't be overidden by browsers as they are [forbidden headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name), which is good enough for many use cases. This answer needs to clarify that.

Comment: @Sumit You know that the answers are licensed under CC BY-SA. You can very much [edit] and update it and I would have happily accepted it rather than complaining. It is this quality that makes a better leader. Anyway, thanks, I've updated it.