# How to only accept local ajax Call

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I want to know how do I only accept **local Ajax call**.
I have some pages that I need to use Ajax, however I don't want any external IP to make ajax call in that address, what should I do?
There is some htaccess command or PHP to stop that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can work for you

Comment: How do I use that on server side?

Comment: @Thavo `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is a PHP object, so you can _only_ use it on the server side. However, I would recommend actually checking the incoming "origin" header of the ajax call, this would be more accurate. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599921/5947043