# Cross Origin post to Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, ruby-on-rails-5, rack-cors

I'm using the rack-cors gem with Rails: 
https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

I need to whitelist ONE domain so that it will allow that domain through. 
[image]

I would think that this would allow traffic from the whitelisted domain . I am making a POST request from https://reflective-basket.surge.sh/  to my rails app. (domain name modified for the sake of this post on stackoverflow)

However, POST requests will not go through.  The destination Rails app says:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

If I remove the `protect from forgery` line from the application controller, (`protect_from_forgery with: :exception`), of course, the app allows all traffic through but this defeats the purpose of having a secure app.

I'm sure this is a common problem (needing a form on website A submit data to website B but only from a certain domain) but this just doesn't seem to work as I would have hoped.  Any pointers?  I'm open to making this work in any way that's possible.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, it's a valid question.

Comment: What you're asking for is how to make API requests with forgery protection and this is simply impossible. You would have to perform a `GET` or `HEAD` request first, fetch the session info and then perform the actual `POST` request you need. I guess you can see why this makes no sense. This is why in API use cases CSRF is disabled.

Comment: `protect_from_forgery with: :exception, unless: :whitelisted_origin?`, create a method called `whitelisted_origin?` in `applicaiton_controller.rb` and check if `request.domain` is a whitelisted origin maybe?

Comment: Yes, you could do as @JoshBrody said but keep in mind that it doesn't provide any security and is easy to fake https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566378/how-secure-is-http-origin